# How could I pause, resume processing from inside my goroutine?

Tags: go

So I have this tiny console application where I am starting a goroutine that just outputs an incrementing number.

I am able to tell it to `start` and `stop` and those commands work fine.

How would I implement the `pause` and `resume` command, I'm not sure how to pass this information in my channel, I can change the channel to accept a `string` or `integer` but not sure how to actually perform the pause?

```
func main() {

    fmt.Println("starting...")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    quit := make(chan bool)
    last := 1

    for {
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

        text = strings.Replace(text, "\n", "", -1)

        fmt.Printf("entered: %s\n", text)

        switch {
        case text == "start":
            fmt.Println("starting")
            go counter(last, 1, quit, &last)
        case text == "pause":
            fmt.Println("pausing")
        case text == "resume":
            fmt.Println("resuming")
        case text == "stop":
            fmt.Println("stopping")
            quit <- true
        }

        fmt.Printf("last is %v", last)

    }
}

func counter(startFrom int, multiplyBy int, quit <-chan bool, last *int) {

    for {
        for x := startFrom; x < 100; x++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)

            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Printf("counter stopped")
                return
            default:
                result := x * multiplyBy
                *last = result
                fmt.Printf("%d", result)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a second channel which you'd then use for pausing/resuming.

Something like this should work:

```golang
func counter(startFrom int, multiplyBy int, quit, pause <-chan bool, last *int) {
    for {
        for x := startFrom; x < 100; x++ {
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1000)

            select {
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Printf("counter stopped")
                return
            case msg := <-pause:
                if msg == true {
                    fmt.Printf("counter paused")

                pause_loop:
                    for {
                        select {
                        case msg := <-pause:
                            if msg == false {
                                fmt.Printf("counter resumed")
                                break pause_loop
                            }
                        case <-quit:
                            fmt.Printf("counter stopped")
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
            default:
                result := x * multiplyBy
                *last = result
                fmt.Printf("%d", result)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need two channels.
quit for quit in goroutine.
paused for pausing and resume,

main function change:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "sync/atomic"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("starting...")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    paused := make(chan bool)
    quit := make(chan bool)
    var last int64 = 1

    for {
        text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        text = strings.Replace(text, "\n", "", -1)

        fmt.Printf("entered: %s\n", text)

        switch {
        case text == "start":
            fmt.Println("starting")
            // create new goroutine
            go counter(last, 1, paused, quit, &last)

        case text == "pause":
            fmt.Println("pausing")
            paused <- true

        case text == "resume":
            fmt.Println("resuming")
            paused <- false

        case text == "stop":
            fmt.Println("stopping")
            quit <- true
        }

        fmt.Printf("last is %v", last)
    }
}
```

and fix counter:

```golang
func counter(
    startFrom, multiplyBy int64,
    paused, quit <-chan bool,
    last *int64,
) {
    var pause bool

    // if startFrom higher 100
    // loop exit and function end
    for startFrom < 100 {
        select {

        // get signal pause
        case p, ok := <-paused:
            // check signal is ok?
            if ok {
                pause = p
            }

        case <-quit:
            fmt.Printf("counter stopped")
            return

        // sleep 1s if not get data
        // from any channels
        // if get new data from channels
        // time restarted
        // and started again
        case <-time.After(time.Millisecond * 1000):

            // if not pause work
            if !pause {
                result := startFrom * multiplyBy

                // use swap atomic
                // if many goroutine runs
                // don't get problem!
                atomic.SwapInt64(last, result)
                startFrom++
                fmt.Printf("%d", result)
            }
        }
    }
}
```